# how to display text view without bracket

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I have an `OnItemClick()`, after that I wanted to get the ItemClicked name's and display it in a `TextView`.
I do it normally, but the problem is that I get the ItemClicked name's inside a bracket! How do I avoid this?
Here is the output:

```
{titre=hello}
```

I want only in my `TextView`:

```
hello.
```

Here is the code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
    displayTextViewTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String value = item.toString();
    displayTextViewTitle.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}
```

Comment: why you are taking Object? it should be your class type. Other give you Generic Class body so that someone can help you.

Comment: How do you fill your ListView?

Comment: i fill my list view from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting your String **{titre=hello}** like this after click on ListView. then you should use this:

```
String[] no = item.split("=");
String m = no[0];
String k = no[1];
String name = k.substring(0, k.length() - 1);
```

***name*** is your final result String .

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    TextView displayTextViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView item = (TextView) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String value = item.getText();
    displayTextViewTitle.setText(value);
}
```

or even better try :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    TextView displayTextViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(yourListViewName);
    String value = lv.get(position).tostring();
    displayTextViewTitle.setText(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

value is already a String, you don't have to use String.valueOf(value).

Answer (score 0):

The listener method works fine, check this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        members.add("titre=hello");
        members.add("world");
        ArrayAdapter s = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, members);
        lv.setAdapter(s);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        TextView displayTextViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String value = item.toString();
        displayTextViewTitle.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

Recheck the values inside your listview, the problem might be there